# STM32F1 SPI-slave without CS

Tags: stm32, spi, embedded

I'm curious is there ability to set STM32 to work as SPI Slave, without CS - just to rely on edges of SPI master's clock?
I want to interface it with ADF7021 which has SPI output(ADF is master) of Received data, but it doesn't have CS.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you using HAL? Or direct register access?

Comment: I think about using HAL

Answer (score 1):

The approach is:

- Configure SPI to use *software slave select* (bit SSM on SPI_CR1 register)
- Trigger the slave select (internally) by setting and clearing the *internal slave select* (bit SSI on SPI_CR1 register)

If you like to, you can permanently set the internal slave select. The SPI peripheral will send and receive data as long as SSI bit is set, driven by the external clock (SCLK).

Using HAL/LL, it looks like so:

**Initialization**

```
hspi.Instance = SPI2;
hspi.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
...
hspi.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
...
HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi);
```

**Setting Slave Select**

```
LL_SPI_SetMode(&hspi, SPI_CR1_SSI);
```

**Clearing Slave Select**

```
LL_SPI_SetMode(&hspi, 0);
```

It can be quite a challenge to provide and consume the SPI data in time as the time and speed of the transmission is driven from the outside. Depending on the speed, a triggered interrupt can be sufficient to miss data. So you probably want to think about using DMA, possibly with a circular buffer.

Comment: Data speed is driven fron outside, so baudrate i set in cubemx doesnt matter?

Comment: Yes, no need to set speed.

Comment: And how will i know when master will stop transmitting?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ADF7021. If it doesn't have a chip select signal, you will need to investigate the other signal. Or it might be using a message format with a predictable length. So by checking the message, you will know if it is complete.